# When iFrame changes page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is there any way you can fire a function when a `iframe` has changed its page (load function), without having to add anything to the `iframe` content?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the iframe contents are from another origin, in which case the answer is no. Browsers won't tell you the current URL of a child iframe unless its same-origin, so I don't think they'll fire an event when it changes.

Here's a demo which recognises when the first load event takes place, but doesn't log any subsequent page changes:
http://jsfiddle.net/GPh6H/